# Mixed color border and background in GradientDrawable

Tags: android

How to get the problem fixed? 
  How custom Shape(Please only programmatically shape)?

```
GradientDrawable  g = new GradientDrawable ();
g.setStroke(17, Color.argb(100,  0,0,255));
g.setColor(Color.rgb(255,  255,0,0));
```

out:

[image: Mixed color(alpha=100) border and background in GradientDrawable]

Comment: use a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` passed to the constructor

Comment: (only programmatically)?

Comment: only programmatically